# Optimal performance for two dim array to datatable conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I was looking for an optimized method to convert a square array of type

double[ , ]

to DataTable

I looked up over the internet and couldn't find a way faster than the currently implemented in my method which depends on two nested for loops.

The problem is that the performance is very bad. My input array could be any where from 500 to 15000 elements in each dimension. (Math can be scary)...

This means that it could take ages for the conversion to complete with the current method.

I was thinking about using some unmanaged code or even assembly code to improve the performance but I didn't know how to do it..

My Current code is this...

```
// helper method to get row as a string array    
private static string[] GetRowFromArray(double[,] array, int column )

{

int dim = array.GetUpperBound(0) +1;

string[] row = new string[dim];

for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++)

{

    row[i] = array[i, column].ToString();

}

return row;

}


//the static extension method used to convert the array to datatable

public static DataTable ToDataTable(this double[,] array)

{

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

int rowsCount = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;

int colsCount = array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

int i = 0;

while (i < colsCount)

{

   dt.Columns.Add(); i++;

}

int ii = 0;

while (ii < rowsCount)

{

    string[] a = GetRowFromArray(array, ii);

    dt.Rows.Add(a);

    ii++;

}

return dt;

}
```

Any ideas on how can we optimize this to make it run faster.

Just a side note, the array is square array, so  ColumnsCount = RowsCount

And so many thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you need it to be in a DataTable? Could you not just get data out of your array instead? Not converting it at all would be super fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize the code by...

1. Eliminating DataTable (just use the array directly).
2. Using jagged arrays and eliminating double to string conversions.

Using DataTable is by far the most significant contributor to poor performance.  But, let's assume you must use DataTable.  In that case, your main problem is the need to construct a single dimension array to provide to the DataRowCollection.Add() method.

By using jagged arrays, you can provide the single dimension array directly.  This speeds up the code almost 7x.

```
Original poster's code ran in 15679 msec.
My code ran in 2261 msec.
My code is 6.94x faster.
```

I believe you transposed the rows and columns in your GetRowFromArray function.  This is apparent if the multi-dimension array is not square.  I realize you said it is, but I wrote my code with separate lengths for x and y.

Here's my code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace DataTable
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const int _xLength = 15000;
        private const int _yLength = 1000;
        private static Random _random;


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[,] array = new double[_xLength, _yLength];
            _random = new Random();
            for (int x = 0; x < _xLength; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < _yLength; y++)
                {
                    array[x, y] = _random.NextDouble();
                }
            }
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            OriginalPoster(array);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan originalCodeDuration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"Original poster's code ran in {originalCodeDuration.TotalMilliseconds:0} msec.");
            array = null;
            GC.Collect();
            double[][] jaggedArray = new double[_xLength][];
            for (int x = 0; x < _xLength; x++)
            {
                jaggedArray[x] = new double[_yLength];
                for (int y = 0; y < _yLength; y++)
                {
                    jaggedArray[x][y] = _random.NextDouble();
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Restart();
            Mine(jaggedArray);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan myCodeDuration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"My code ran in {myCodeDuration.TotalMilliseconds:0} msec.");
            double speedUp = originalCodeDuration.TotalMilliseconds / myCodeDuration.TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"My code is {speedUp:0.00}x faster.");
        }


        private static void OriginalPoster(double[,] array)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            int rowsCount = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int colsCount = array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < colsCount)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(); i++;
            }
            int ii = 0;
            while (ii < rowsCount)
            {
                string[] a = GetRowFromArray(array, ii);
                dt.Rows.Add(a);
                ii++;
            }
        }


        private static string[] GetRowFromArray(double[,] array, int rowNumber)
        {
            int dim = array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
            string[] row = new string[dim];
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            {
                row[i] = array[rowNumber, i].ToString();
            }
            return row;
        }


        private static void Mine(double[][] Array)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            for (int y = 0; y < _yLength; y++)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add();
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < _xLength; x++)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(Array[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and useful reply you provided. Exceptional  effort there Sir. I am going to test it as soon as I get back home and Mark It as answer hopefully.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. That worked for me. I am now able to perform required operations in a relatively acceptable time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could parallelize it. In the sample code, the number of dimensions tasks are created and run in parallel.

```
    private static string[] GetRowFromArray(double[,] array, int column)
    {
        int dim = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        string[] row = new string[dim];

        //for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        Parallel.For(0, dim, i =>
        {
            row[i] = array[i, column].ToString();
        });

        return row;
    }
```

You can control the level of parallelism by

```
        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dim;

        Parallel.For(0, dim, options, i =>
        {
            row[i] = array[i, column].ToString();
        });
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. I noticed that the most time consuming part of the method is in the second method :: exactly in dt.Rows.Add(a);

Comment: You can parallelize it too. Just try my code first to get familiar with it.

Comment: I am going to try it and give my feedback , hope it works, and so many thanks , Sir

Comment: Hello again. I tried your code and it works fine but sadly with no performance improvement over the original.  I also tried to make both parallel but actually it just got worst as I think I  get a huge overhead . Either ways it doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something here?